Why Flexible Widget causes overflows?
Im trying to figure out why in the tablet screen i have overflows i also used fit: FlexFit.tight, but still no luck, how i can stop a widget from overflow?
Also why does not Singlechildscrollview is not working ?
If i remove the constraints then it crashes and if i put more height then the buttons and all of my widgets get insane margins between them , maybe because flex getting bigger.
Thanks i post a picture also .
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        // width: screenWidth,
        // height: screenHeight,
        decoration: ContainerStyles.gradientBoxDecoration,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints:
                BoxConstraints(maxHeight: screenHeight, maxWidth: screenWidth),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Big_Texts(
                        bigText: AppLocale.getString(
                            context, AppLocale.register_big_text,
                            languageCode: current_locale),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(screenWidth * 0.05),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Custom_TextField(
                          labelTexts: AppLocale.getString(
                              context, AppLocale.username_textfield,
                              languageCode: current_locale),
                          havePassword: false,
                          themeController: usernameController,
                          icon: Icons.person,
                        ),
                        Big_Spacer(),
                        Custom_TextField(
                          labelTexts: AppLocale.getString(
                              context, AppLocale.password_textfield,
                              languageCode: current_locale),
                          havePassword: true,
                          themeController: passwordController,
                          icon: Icons.lock,
                        ),
                        Big_Spacer(),
                        Custom_TextField(
                          labelTexts: AppLocale.getString(
                              context, AppLocale.repeat_password_textfield,
                              languageCode: current_locale),
                          havePassword: true,
                          themeController: repeatPasswordController,
                          icon: Icons.lock,
                        ),
                        Big_Spacer(),
                        Custom_TextField(
                          labelTexts: AppLocale.getString(
                              context, AppLocale.email_textfield,
                              languageCode: current_locale),
                          havePassword: false,
                          themeController: emailController,
                          icon: Icons.email,
                        ),
                        Big_Spacer(),
                        Custom_TextField(
                          labelTexts: AppLocale.getString(
                              context, AppLocale.carModel_textfield,
                              languageCode: current_locale),
                          havePassword: false,
                          themeController: carInfoController,
                          icon: Icons.car_rental,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Big_Button(
                        buttonText: AppLocale.getString(
                            context, AppLocale.register_button,
                            languageCode: current_locale),
                        onPressed: () async {
       //register fuctionality 
                                  
                        },
                      ),
                      Big_Spacer(),
                      Secondary_Big_Button(
                        buttonText: AppLocale.getString(
                            context, AppLocale.back_button,
                            languageCode: current_locale),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Go_Back(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

my textfield widget :
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        return TextField(
          obscureText: havePassword!,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            //floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
            labelText: labelTexts,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white70,
              fontFamily: GoogleFonts.akatab().fontFamily,
              fontSize: constraints.maxWidth * 0.04,
            ),
            // hintText: '............',
            // hintStyle: TextStyle(
            //   color: Colors.white70,
            //   fontFamily: GoogleFonts.akatab().fontFamily,
            //   fontSize: custom_textField_sizes.fontSize1,
            // ),
            icon: Icon(icon,
                color: Colors.white70, size: constraints.maxWidth * 0.08),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.white70, width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.005),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(constraints.maxWidth * 0.01),
              ),
            ),
            contentPadding:
                EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(constraints.maxWidth * 0.01, 0, 0, 0),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.white70, width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.01),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(constraints.maxWidth * 0.01),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white70, fontSize: constraints.maxWidth * 0.1),
          controller: themeController,
          autofillHints: autofillHints,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}




Just add the scroll direction of the SingleChildScrollView It will be fix.
child: SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  child: //Other Widgets
)


when you use flexible, it will split the screen to some part based on your total flex.
from your code the screen will split to 4 section with the same height.
title = 1/4 * screen_height
form = 2/4 * screen_height
button = 1/4 * screen_height

in your case, the form height actually is more than the height it set, here is the section look like

Your SingleChildScrollView is not working because you use it outside. Eventhough the problem is the form section is too long. So you can try to move the SingleChildScrollView inside of the form section.
The widgets will be look like this :
Column(
    Flex 1 -> title section
    Flex 2 -> form section
    Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(screenWidth * 0.05),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      // form content
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    Flex 1 -> button section
)

